# unknown column in fireld list- mysql python connector-insertion

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, mysql-python

```
    c.execute('show tables')
    for i in c:
        print(i)
    t=input('enter exact table name')
    n=0
    c.execute('show columns from {}'.format(t))
    records=c.fetchall()
    print(records)
    for i in records:
        n=n+1
    a=1
    data=''
    while a!=0:
        for i in range(n):
            v=input("enter data")
            if i==n-1:
                data=data+v
            else:
                data=data+v+','
        print(data)
        print('insert into {} values{}'.format(t,data))
        c.execute('insert into {} values({})'.format(t,data))
```

in this code i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subra\OneDrive\Desktop\netflix.py", line 62, in <module>
    create_input()
  File "C:\Users\subra\OneDrive\Desktop\netflix.py", line 51, in create_input
    c.execute('insert into {} values{}'.format(t,data))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 599, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 487, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'subru' in 'field list'
```

can anyone help me out on how to avoid this error
i have also made sure that there is only 1 table and that is the one i am inserting

this is the output that i get including the input vales:

```
>>>('hellopython',)
>>>enter exact table namehellopython
>>>[('student', b'varchar(30)', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('rollno', b'varchar(30)', 'YES', '', None,'')]
>>>enter datasubru
>>>enter data29
>>>(subru,29)
>>>insert into hellopython values(subru,29)

***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subra\OneDrive\Desktop\netflix.py", line 62, in <module>
    create_input()
  File "C:\Users\subra\OneDrive\Desktop\netflix.py", line 51, in create_input
    c.execute('insert into {} values{}'.format(t,data))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 599, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\subra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 487, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'subru' in 'field list'***
```

Comment: Can you also explain what are you trying to achieve here and what was your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around the data.

So MySQL thinks that subru is not a name. instead he thninks it is a column name

```
if i==n-1:
    data=data+"'"+v+ "'"
else:
    data=data+"'"+v+ "'"+','
print(data)
print('insert into {} values{}'.format(t,data))
c.execute('insert into {} values({})'.format(t,data))
```